# Help solving a 2nd-order RLC circuit

Tags: dc, current-source, passive-networks

This is the practice problem 8.9 of Fundamentals of Electric Circuits 5th Edition.

[image]

Can someone help me with this question? I need a more detailed solution of this problem. Especially, what are the initial conditions. I though, by turning of the independent source, it should be i'' + 7*i' + 10*i = 0, and the initial conditions should be i(0)=0, and di(0)/dt=0.

But my solution turns out to be incorrect. Where did I make the mistake? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**The differential equation:**
Current \$i\$ flows through the right branch and \$3-i\$ flows through left branch. So we can write:

$$10(3-i)+20\int(3-i)dt = 4i+2\frac{di}{dt}\tag1$$

which can be differentiated and re-arranged to get the equation:

$$y'' + 7y' + 10y = 30\tag2$$

The equation you obtained assumes that same current \$i\$ flows through both the branches.

**The initial conditions:**
The first initial condition you obtained is correct but the second one is wrong.

$$\frac{di}{dt}(0)\ne 0$$

At \$t=0,\$ capacitor can be considered as short circuit and inductor can be considered as open circuit. Then voltage across current source and hence the voltage across inductor will be 30V.

$$2\frac{di}{dt}(0) = 30$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{di}{dt}(0) = 15$$

so the initial conditions are:

$$i(0) = 0; \frac{di}{dt}(0) = 15\tag3$$

Solving the differential equation in (2) with initial conditions in (3) will give you the required answer.